# multicols environment drops flowfram's frames

Tags: multicol, flowfram

In the following MWE, the vertical stripe (provided by the `flowfram`'s `\vNtonetop` static frame) takes effect on each page. But as soon as the `multicol`'s `multicols` environment is commented out, the stripe is dropped from the page where `multicols` starts until the page before it ends (see image below).

Do you know the reason of this and how to circumvent it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{flowfram}
%
\vNtonetop{1}{1cm}{\paperwidth}{gray}{topleft}
\newflowframe{\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
%
\begin{document}
\section{One Column}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{One or Two Columns}
% \begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-10]
% \end{multicols}
\section{One Column}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using flowfram and multicol on the same text at the same time is so brave:-)

Comment: I know that ;) But, AFAICS, that's the only way to get one and two columns on the same page: `\twocolumninarea` necessarily starts a new page.

Comment: does your real case have more use of flowfram, here you just seem to have one full page frame so it isn't really being used (the bar could be added by less invasive methods)

Comment: My real case has more use of `flowfram` but, indeed, I guess I could achieve the same result with other tools, such as `textpos` and `background`. I'm nevertheless intrigued by the reason why `multicols` environment drops `flowfram`'s frames.

Comment: I could look but honestly I'm surprised that you get any output at all. Nicola or Frank could probably make more informed comments but both packages are making highly invasive changes into the output routine to do what they do, and tex only has one output routine active so unless the two packages are explicitly written to share the same output routine things being dropped is the expected behaviour. (This is why longtable doesn't work in multicols for example)

Comment: Just compile the MWE I provided and you'll see you can trust me :) But don't waste your time: I'll probably try to get the same result without `flowfram`.